# React Hooks and Enzyme: React keeps telling me to wrap state updates in act(...), even thought I did

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-dom

I've been teaching myself how to test react components with `enzyme` and `jest`, but I'm clueless as to how to test a **mounted** component which uses React hooks.

Here is a simplified version of the component...

```
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

  const onChange = async ({ value }) => {
    try {
      const request = await searchRecords();

      console.log("Before setRecords");

      setRecords(request.results);

      console.log("After setRecords");
    } catch (error) {  /* error handling */ }
  }
```

The test code looks like...

```
let wrapped;

describe("Sample", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    wrapped = mount(
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {})}>
        <Sample />
      </Provider>
    );
    api.mockImplementation(() => ({ results: searchResult }));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapped.unmount();
  });

  it("shows items in the search box", () => {
    wrapped.find("#searchField")
      .simulate("change", { target: { value: "blah blah" } });
    // This triggers "onChange" function

    wrapped.update();

    expect(wrapped.find("li").length).toEqual(10);  
    // If "setRecords()" hook works, there will be 10 "li" elements
  });
});
```

The test itself passes, but I see the following message in CLI.

```
Warning: An update to SearchBox inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
```

Following [the link provided in the warning message](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act), I surrounded the lines which updated the state.

i.e.

```
act(() => {
  wrapped.find("#searchField").simulate("change", { target: { value: "red" } });
});
```

Still, the warning message persists. Just in case, I surrounded the `mount(...)`  part, but it doesn't change anything.

In the test examples on [React's doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act), `enzyme` isn't used, so I feel like `React Hooks` are not compatible with `enzyme`.

How can we remove the warning message while still using `enzyme`? Or, is `enzyme` really incompatible?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap mount function with act as well... Looking at the example even render function is wrapped with `act()`: https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html#testing-hooks

Comment: I'm also seeing this, with seemingly no reason

Comment: I had a similar issue. You need to post more of your component as I suspect that something async is called where/when you haven't wrapped it.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issues - all tests pass, but I get this error message for each instance of `expect` that I have in my test file. I've wrapped everything in `act(()` and `act(async()` etc.

Comment: @barryman9000 when I've had it there was a 'hidden' update in my non-simplified version of the component. I don't think I could find it now though, so I'm not sure I could answer this either.

Comment: @Barryman9000 I stopped using Enzyme and started to use react-testing-library